# Photoshop draw circle from line

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, shapes

How can i turn this line into a circle in photoshop cs6 ?

I want to draw a circle with this texture

[image: 1]

This is **not** how I want to draw my Circle. I want to copy then rotate and then paste the first image's texture many times, to create a circle shape, not like the below image where it looks like a STOP sign. (It should have a circle inside since the image would be created by keep copying and rotating the first image to fill all the pixels)

[image: 2]

Comment: Homework assignment? What have you tried?

Comment: I am a programmer trying to make my own graphics in my game. This is texture is used to create a lightning animation programmatically. What I have tried is googling for the past 3 hours, I have no prior knowledge of photoshop apart from basics. I suppose one way to do it is manually copy and paste it 200~ times. But that would take me a while

Comment: @Scott any better suggestions, are highly appreciated

Comment: Seems to be you could simply draw two circles and an an outer glow to the inner small circle.

Comment: @Scott This is actually very smart, I might have to do it that way if it there is no other way to recreate the exact texture I have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything automated to rotate a vertical tile around it's center. You'd have to manually copy and rotate. You could use the `Transform Again` function in the `Edit` menu, but it would still be fairly tedious.

My suggestion is to draw 2 circles, then apply an **Outer Glow Layer Style** to the inner circle.

[image]

If you need the inner circle to be a "hole" or counter, you'll need a third circle which matches the size of the inner circle. And you'll want to draw the first inner circle with the `Subtract Front Shape` path mode set so it removed the center of the larger circle.

[image]

The third circle would have a `Fill Opacity` set to `0%` so the fill isn't visible, but the outer glow is.

[image]

(Note the counter in the bottom layer)

You could also use one shape with a gradient overlay....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is that could work first draw lines

[image]

marge the line shape and get the circle selection on it... and mask it.

[image]